# Data missing on Python request (AJAX request)

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape historical weather data from this website:
http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/dailyExtract_uc.htm?y=2016&m=1

After some reading on the AJAX call, I found the proper way to request data is through the following code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

headers = {
'Accept': 'text/plain, */*; q=0.01',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Host': 'www.hko.gov.hk',
'Referer': 'http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/dailyExtract_e.htm?y=2016&m=3',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
#request April 2015 weather data
    r = s.get(r"http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/dailyExtract/dailyExtract_201504.xml",verify = False, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.get_text())['stn']['data'][0]['dayData'][:-2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I noticed the data I retrieved does not contain the 3 columns on the right hand side, what did I miss in the get request?

Comment: Note, despite the extension, that endpoint is returning JSON not XML. There is no need to use BeautifulSoup at all; just do `data = r.json()`.

Comment: Is it because you're slicing the list `[:-2]` ?

Comment: The slicing is to take away the bottom two rows which is the mean/total data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes you are right, did not realise that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems if you request entire year then extract month it is there

```
import requests
import json

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(r"http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/dailyExtract/dailyExtract_2015.xml",headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).json()
    print(r['stn']['data'][3]['dayData'][0])
```

Comment: Yea I realised I got confused on the URLs, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I have solved the issue and this is a stupid question....
Turns out the older data has a different source than the recent ones and I got confused on the format.

Answer (score 0):

fix the request Url. Change:

```
http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/dailyExtract/dailyExtract_201504.xml
```

to

```
http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/dailyExtract/dailyExtract_2015.xml
```

then you can grab the 4th element (or some other specific month) in the list `data['stn']['data']`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

headers = {
'Accept': 'text/plain, */*; q=0.01',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Host': 'www.hko.gov.hk',
'Referer': 'http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/dailyExtract_e.htm?y=2016&m=3',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
#request April 2015 weather data
    data = s.get(r"http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/dailyExtract/dailyExtract_2015.xml",verify = False, headers = headers).json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['stn']['data'][3]['dayData'])
```